# format for request to azure analysis services rest api

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-analysis-services

I am refreshing a data model in azure analysis services using a rest api.

Refrence doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh#base-url

I am getting a HTTPError 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url. What is the correct way to format the request?

```
import requests
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# URL for the Azure Analysis Services REST API
url = "https://uksouth.asazure.windows.net/servers/myserver/models/mymodel/refreshes"

# get token
resource_uri = "https://uksouth.asazure.windows.net"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = credential.get_token(resource_uri)
access_token = token.token

# Prepare the headers
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}

# Prepare the body for a full refresh
body = {
    "Type": "Full"
}

# Make the POST request
try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print("Model refresh triggered successfully")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to trigger model refresh: {e}")
    raise e
```

Full error

HTTP error occurred: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://uksouth.asazure.windows.net/servers/myserver/models/mymodel/refreshes
Response Status Code: 400
Response Text: {"code":"Unauthorized","subCode":0,"message":"An internal error occurred.","timeStamp":"2024-01-04T13:42:01.4233221Z","httpStatusCode":400

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you may want to check.

1. Which type of credential you expect to work. DefaultAzureCredential is a chain of different types of credentials. If none of them works, you will not be able to get a valid token. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity/README.md#defaultazurecredential
2. The scope, credential.get_token(scope) is used to get the token and you need to specify the correct scope string to let the server know which resource you want to access. e.g. the scope for accessing ARM resources is "https://management.azure.com/.default".

Hope this helps.

(I work in Azure SDK team in Microsoft)

Comment: if i am using user-assigned managed identity which i setup for azure analysis services using a bicep template and gave admin rights (was missing this before possible reason for error). I only have 1 asssignment. would default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential() be okay or would i do the following DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id)

Comment: You need DefaultAzureCredential(managed_identity_client_id=client_id) or put the client id into environment variable "AZURE_TENANT_ID"